# Domain - The DNS has been propagated or not?

Tags: dns, subdomain, host, whois

Made the purchase of a domain in a Brazilian company called UOL (Universo Online).
Once the domain has been registered, it came with the following standard DNS:

```
Nameserver: ns1.dominios.uol.com.br
Nameserver: ns2.dominios.uol.com.br
Nameserver: ns3.dominios.uol.com.br
```

I went into my hosting server and got the DNS server for me to upgrade in the field.
The DNS of the server hosting is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKDkT.jpg

Went on the control panel of the company that bought the domain (UOL), removed the default DNS (ns1.dominios.uol.com.br, ns2 ... ns3 ...) and I upgraded to DNS of my webhost:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWWrP.jpg

The company gave me a deadline 24-48 hours for DNS propagation.

I decided to enter the "intoDNS" (www.intodns.com) to check the situation and noticed that an error appears, see:

http://www.intodns.com/kiararockswithgnr.com

Is something wrong? Or is the DNS has not yet been propagated and I just wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the whois, the name servers for the domain are

```
Name Server: NS1.HOSTINGER.COM.BR
Name Server: NS2.HOSTINGER.COM.BR
Name Server: NS3.HOSTINGER.COM.BR
```

and this is confirmed by the DNS delegation

```
dig kiararockswithgnr.com +trace

kiararockswithgnr.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns1.hostinger.com.br.
kiararockswithgnr.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns2.hostinger.com.br.
kiararockswithgnr.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns3.hostinger.com.br.
;; Received 109 bytes from 192.42.93.30#53(192.42.93.30) in 2454 ms
```

If this is not what you are seeing, it's likely you are hitting a cached result.

Comment: whois is not the tool to use to check for DNS records, the DNS is. To see if changes have been applied to the registry DNS servers, first ask the registry authoritative nameservers about the domain names involved and its NS records. When these are updated, you can start to query recursive nameserver, both public (like 8.8.8.8 or 9.9.9.9) or private (your own, your ISP, etc.) to see their view of the thing, and specifically if they have old records the attached TTLs.